# SQL Server batch performance optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-processing

We have the following architecture

- Staging table
- Read table

The staging table is a direct load from an external database and once a week, data from the staging table is loaded into the Read table and has a few inner joins to reduce reads when a user hits the read table. The issue is the volume of data in the Staging table is large enough that it's capped out our DB LOG so we've been requested to implement batching.

I have the below script, which works, but as of now it's only running on a 1/8th of the data we need to migrate and it's taking approximately 4 hours to run. The volume of records in the staging table is approximately 80 million records and Table2 is approximate 400 records w/ indexes, uniques, and PK applied.

```
DECLARE @PageSize int = 50000;
DECLARE @PageIndex int = 0;
DECLARE @TotalPages int = 0;


SELECT @TotalPages = ((count(1) / @PageSize) + 1)
FROM Table1_Staging t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.r1 = t1.r7
INNER JOIN Table2 t3 ON t3.r1 = t1.r8

SELECT @TotalPages;

WHILE (@PageIndex <= @TotalPages)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO Table1 ( [row1], [row2], [row3], [row4],
                              [row5], [row6], [row7], [row8])
        SELECT  t1.r2,
                t1.r3,
                t2.r1,
                t2.r3,
                t3.r3,
                t1.r6,
                IIF(TRY_CONVERT(datetime, t1.DATE) IS NULL,
                    DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()),
                    TRY_CONVERT(datetime, t1.DATE))
                    AS date,
                t1.r1
        FROM Table1_Staging t1
                    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.r1 = t1.r7
                    INNER JOIN Table2 t3 ON t3.r1 = t1.r8
        ORDER BY t1.r2 DESC
        OFFSET (@PageSize * @PageIndex) ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    /** Increments the Page Size */
    SET @PageIndex  = @PageIndex  + 1;
END
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on optimizing this query or a different way of batch loading the data in SQL only? The indexes and PK applied to all tables have been optimized for the query. Or should I just increase the PageSize to something large like 500,000.

Comment: Have you considered using `BULK INSERT` instead? Also, if you have only a single `INSERT` statement then your `BEGIN TRANSACTION/COMMIT TRANSACTION` statements are redundant (_or_ move the transaction block outside your `WHILE LOOP` if you don't mind a very long commit time).

Comment: Rather than control batching with row-number pagination, consider key-based pagination for the batching. I can't suggest specifics due to the obfuscated column names and no details of existing indexes.

Comment: @Dai, BULK INSERT is only for reading from external files. I was told the BEGIN TRANSACTION needs to be inside the WHILE LOOP as when that hits, the DB LOG will treat it as a commit (That could be wrong though)

Comment: Really, you should just allocate more space for the log files instead of complicating your ETL.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft unfortunately that's not an option, we're in a shared environment and are a non-mission critical application so our DBAs don't want special exceptions for our DB, but our business partners want the data. Kind of stuck between a rock and a rock here.

Comment: @DanGuzman, this is what I was looking for, thanks it turned the query from hours to minutes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The optimization we ended up going with was the following:
Adding an IDENTITY INT primary key on the staging table, removing the row-number pagination and going with a KEYSET pagination. Reduced the 4 hour query to about 22 minutes.

```
DECLARE @PageSizeCurrent int = 0;
DECLARE @PageSizeIncrement int = 50000;
DECLARE @rowCount int = 1;

WHILE (@rowCount > 0)
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO Table1 ([row1], [row2], [row3], [row4],
                        [row5], [row6], [row7], [row8])
        SELECT  
            t1.r2, t1.r3, t2.r1, t2.r3,
            t3.r3, t1.r6, 
            IIF(TRY_CONVERT(datetime, t1.DATE) IS NULL, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, 
                 GETDATE()),
            TRY_CONVERT(datetime, t1.DATE)) AS date,
            t1.r1
        FROM 
            Table1_Staging t1
        INNER JOIN 
            Table2 t2 ON t2.r1 = t1.r7
        INNER JOIN 
            Table2 t3 ON t3.r1 = t1.r8
    WHERE t1.[id] > @PageSize AND t1.[id] < (@PageSize + @PageSizeIncrement)

    SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT


    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    /** Increments the Page Size */
    SET @PageSize = @PageSize + @PageSizeIncrement;
END
```